# How to get rid of "Folders" and "Network locations" links in Explorer in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-8.1

Let me explain with a couple of screenshots. I just upgraded from Windows 8 to 8.1 and now I get a bunch of useless shortcuts in Windows Explorer when I try to open a file, or if I just plainly go to `My Computer`. Stuff like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Can I hide the links circled in red?

The reason I don't need them there is because now I have to constantly scroll down to get to the files and folders that I actually need. (And if I fold them up with that little arrow, they come right out after a while.) It just wastes time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the tool called [This PC Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.213), this tool allows you to remove and add new folders:

> With This PC Tweaker, you will be able to perform the following
>   customizations:
>
> - to add any folder to the Computer/This PC folder. Really any.
> - to remove any folder from the Computer/This PC folder.
> - to change the icon for any folder inside Computer/This PC.
> - to add any shell location like Administrative tools, God Mode, Network Connections
> - you can pin or unpin Computer/This PC items from the Navigation Pane of Explorer in Windows 8.1, Windows 8 and even in Windows 7!
> - You can remove or add any item from the Folders category inside the Computer/This PC folder.
> - to restore defaults with one click.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do this with MS tools or via registry? I need to do it on an AD for multiple PCs.

Comment: yes, look here: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/42957/windows-8-1-hide-librar-folders-in-my-computer/

Comment: Thanks. Also found this: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/28025-pc-add-remove-folders-windows-8-1-a.html